# Turn off notification bar iPhone from app

Tags: iphone, notifications

I want to turn off notification bar when my app is running on iPhone. How can I prevent it from showing that bar? Actually, the problem is when it appears on the top of my app it disturbs the layout of the app.

Comment: Could you provide the code, a stripped down version of the project or screenshots?